Is there a way to change location of wwwroot folder in maui blazor hybrid app
I am going to write a blazor hybrid app with a separate project for razor components.
I found how to add a reference to wwwroot from the component project to the hybrid project.
Then I wanted to hide wwwroot in the "Resources" folder, but I could not find any information on how to do this. Is there a way to do this and is it a bad practice?
I tried to make it work like it does in real web apps, but it instantly failed because AppBuilders implement different interfaces for different projects

You can try to move the wwwroot to the "Resources" folder and then in MainPage.xaml, change the HostPage  to HostPage="Resources/wwwroot/index.html".

This method did not help. I need to somehow force the system to change default path of wwwroot.

You may not be able to force the system to change default path of wwwroot folder, however, you can refer to this potential workaround.
